# Convert sql query in to Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ROR technology. If someone can help me to convert below sql query into Active Record rails

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE users SET score = score + #{total_score} WHERE users.event_id = #{event_id} AND (team_players @> ARRAY[1]::integer[])")
```

Trying to update users.score table and add total_score(variable) when condition match.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Rails setup, though I don't find it much cleaner than your code really.

```
User.where(event_id: event_id)
  .where('team_players @> ARRAY[1]::integer[]')
  .update_all("score = score + #{total_score}")
```